# How do I get my code to store all values of an SQLite column in an ArrayList as opposed to just distinct values?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an SQLite database. I have a column called `KEY_NAME` which is a column where each entry is text. I want to output the data as an ArrayList. I am trying to get the code to grab all the values in the table and print them to my console.

```
 if (Cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
                KEY_NAME.add(Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));


                } while (Cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            Cursor.close();
```

But the problem is this code doesn't print all of them, just distinct values. For example, it should print `[Test,Test2,Test2,Test]` but instead it just prints `[Test,Test2]`

How do I get it to print all the values and not just distinct ones?

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getAllIntegerValues() {
    ArrayList<Integer> yourIntegerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Cursor result = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] {KEY_SWITCH}, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    if (Cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                      KEY_NAME.add(Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));


                      } while (Cursor.moveToNext());
               }
              Cursor.close();

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(yourIntegerValues.toArray()));
    return yourIntegerValues;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to store all the rows in an `ArrayList`?

Comment: I just want to store all the values in one column. And the reason is because I plan to have numbers and I want to then convert the results to matrices and use a Java statistical package

Comment: Can you add your query and what KEY_NAME is?

Comment: Did it. Let me know if u need more

Comment: for some unexplainable reason, having "true" inside the query statement was what screwed up everything. I have no idea why this is the case. removing it fixed everything.